# SOA: service API discover

Tags: soa

At work, me and my colleagues, uses geterogenous SOA. We do not use WS, prefering REST and some binary and JSON-based protocols. Due to it, we do not have WSDL-scheme of our service interfaces.
We faced problem providing information about services to our developers, cause they code in different languages, and not always posess information about all services.
The question is - how to solve this problem?
Organize wiki-system, describing each service separately? Store wsdl-like definitions in service registry? What is the best approach?

Comment: In this case documenting everything is the most important feed to the developers. Urls, input-output, request settings (get/post) anything would be greater than nothing.

Comment: I personally like the GitHub api (http://developer.github.com/v3/), which is build using nanoc (http://nanoc.ws/), a static site generator.
But you're probably after the holy grail and want an auto-generated, always up-to-date version. Not sure, did you check the list of api documentation tools at http://www.mattsilverman.com/2013/02/tools-to-generate-beautiful-api-documentation.html ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try "Swagger" a framework implementation for describing RESTful web services licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 https://developers.helloreverb.com/swagger/